# install old php extension ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, phpmotion

I want to install the phpmotion on Ubuntu 14.04. I need to use it for php 5.3, and older. I did the PHP installation package but I can not attach extensions. How can I do?

Comment: @Gelaber: you should provide at least an error message because otherwise nobody will be able to help you. Besides that: I am sure you know that 5.3 is ancient, do you ?

Comment: i take phpshield error. i install but see php version 5.5.9 because php-gd etc extensions use default php version. just give phpshield error and i must install php5.3 or lower version but i dont know how i can. i try ppa but i used packages are broken or not found

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure how to get an old copy of PHP 5.3 except from compiling it yourself; it's past end of life so you might be better off finding a newer library than risking the security of your entire application.

The [Ondřej Surý PHP 5.4 repo](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-oldstable) is your best bet to get an older version, though it's one ahead of the version you suggest.

Comment: phpmotion use php5.3 and lower and i have problem with phpshield when i compiling ,error: phpshield is not  install

Comment: I'd look for a better piece of software; something that only supports PHP 5.3 doesn't sound like a good quality thing to try and use. Either way, this probably isn't the help site you need; check Server fault or Ask Ubuntu for information about installing out-of-date software.